# Error al instalar pylint en Mac OS

Tags: python, python-2.7, vscode

Buen dia estoy trabajando en Mac, python 2.7.10 y con VSCode y me sale una notificación diciendo lo siguiente: **Linter pylint is not installed.**

Le doy click en instalar y comienza a descargar pero al final marca los siguientes errores y por obvias razones no se instala.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in ma
in
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342,
in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in in
stall
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, i
n install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064,
in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_whe
el_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in
ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, i
n makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enum'
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error ocurre porque para instalar aplicaciones en el Python del sistema se requieren permisos de superusuario.

Sin embargo, es importante hacer notar, que **es altamente recomendable *NO* usar esa versión de Python** para desarrollo y tampoco es recomendable instalar paquetes en esa versión.

Como alternativa puedes instalar [Hombebrew](https://brew.sh/index_es.html) o bien [Pyenv](https://brew.sh/index_es.html) y usarlas para instalar versiones locales de Python que no entren en conflicto con la versión del sistema.

> #### Nota
>
> Para instalar el paquete indicado en la versión del sistema de Python, tendrías que usar este comando:
>
> ```
>  sudo pip -H install pylint
> ```
>
> en una ventana de terminal.

Comment: Perfecto funcionó, y sobre la información adicional, he leído y se ve interesante. Le daré una oportunidad.